# .so file can't "see" the libraries that was compiled with

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, shared-libraries, linkage

I'm trying to create a .so file of caffe (so it will be loaded in Java). I created this .cpp file (more or less):

```
#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
#include "caffe/layers/data_layer.hpp"
using namespace caffe;
using boost::shared_ptr;

class MinimalClassifier
{
    public:
    MinimalClassifier(const char* deploy_path, const char* model_path);
    MinimalClassifier(const char* deploy_path, void* data, int size);
    ~MinimalClassifier();
    float* classify(float* input);
    int input_size();
    int output_size();
    bool gpu_active() { return _gpu; }
    void prepocdefs();
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(caffe_interface)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(/home/ubuntu/caffe3/caffe/cmake_build/install/include/ ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SOURCE_FILES caffe_interface.cpp)
add_library(caffe_interface SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(caffe_interface /home/ubuntu/caffe3/caffe/cmake_build/lib ${CUDA_LIBS})
```

I created (using make) a caffe library named `libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3` that contains all the caffe files.
I connected the .os file and the caffe library with `target_link_libraries` in the CMakeLists.

The thing is that I want my .so file to be linked and depend on that caffe library that I created. But If I do `ldd caffe_interface.so`, the caffe lib doesn't appear in the dependencies there, and therefore It doesn't act as I wan't afterwards. 
What should I do so caffe_interface will depend on the caffe lib?

Comment: Well, you don't link your `caffe_interface` to `libcaffe.so`, no?

Comment: Right, well, I'm trying to understand what to do in order to link the two..

Comment: Provide the full path to that library in `target_link_liraries` call instead of a directory path.

Comment: target_link_libraries does not accept a library folder it gets path to files read the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: Thanks! now ldd really asks for the library. However, even though I'm giving him the file in the same directory, it shows: 
libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3 => not found
Do you know what can I do?

Comment: is `libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3` the exact file-name? I believe it should be something like libcaffe.so just check it.

Comment: It is :( any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. as arrowd suggested, you need to specify the exact file, but it should not be the `*.so.1.0.0` file, but the `*.so` file which is a link to the `*.so.1.0.0` file. 
That's it.